# Can't close opening chrome windows from setTimeout in callback from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

So part of my code is the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < torrentLinks.length; i++) {
    chrome.windows.create({ url: torrentLinks[i] }, function(newWindow) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            chrome.windows.remove(newWindow.id);
        }, 4000);
    });
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that I can open the windows I want but they never close automatically. I'm assuming the setTimeout function is not working so I would like some help with that or an alternative.

NOTE: Every day there is a different number of windows opening when I use the extension so I need all of them to close no matter how many they are.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific about what you expect to happen, what is actually happening, and what is going wrong.

Comment: I expect magnet links to open in a new window each and after 4 seconds  to close. So far they open but they don't close unless I close them manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < torrentLinks.length; i++)
{
chrome.windows.create({url:torrentLinks[i]}, function(newWindow)
{
    window.setTimeout(function() //Forgot the window part
    {
    chrome.windows.remove(newWindow.id);
    }, 4000);
});}
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout` vs `setTimeout` shouldn't matter unless there is a locally defined version of `setTimeout`.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses guys, but it doesn't seem to be working. The windows remain open even after 4 seconds.